# How to put the caption of a TikZ Picture below an image when using overlay option?

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

How to put the caption of a figure below an image when using overlay option? I want to avoid to shift the caption manually via `\vspace{}` or something like that.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[a4paper,left=10mm,right=10mm,top=10mm,bottom=10mm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}%
\begin{document}

% This doesn't work => caption is inside of the picture //overlay is used!
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My Caption}
\end{figure}
\vfill

\clearpage

% This works => caption is inside below the picture //overlay is not used!
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My Caption}
\end{figure}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `\begin{figure}[p]`?

Comment: ... and if you really want to use your construct of manually placing the image in the centre of the page, why use a `figure` environment at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to use `overlay` there, but you could place the caption below the node with the image:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (img) at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[below=0cm of img,text width=\linewidth,anchor=north] {{\captionof{figure}{My Caption}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I searched for!

Comment: @PascalS I'm not convinced that using this is good idea.

Comment: In this case the center of the page is also the center of the text area (due to the margins).